# Use of "and" with multiple verbs

Tags: verbs

Which one is correct?

> He was carrying two ice cream cones and **talked** to a little boy.

or

> He was carrying two ice cream cones and **talking** to a little boy.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean. The first has only the first verb in a clearly continuous sense, while the second has them both that way.

- I was carrying two ice cream cones when I ran into the little boy.
- I was carrying two ice cream cones all the while I was talking to the little boy.

Which sense did you mean?

Comment: Your first sentence is correct grammatically but the verb you chose -run- has not the same property as "talk" when considered telicity / atelicity. So it is not good example. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

When we considered telicity (being complete in some sense) and atelicity (being uncomplete in some sense) of verbs, the first sentence seems unacceptable. If the verb is atelic -e.g meet, you may use the construction as in

I was carrying two ice cream cones and I met the little boy.

if the verb is not atelic you may not construct sentences as in your first example.  I believe the verb **talk** is **atelic**.

Your second sentence is correct.

Answer (score -2):

**Correct**:

> He was carrying two ice cream cones and talking to a little boy.

**Grammatically Incorrect**:

> He was carrying two ice cream cones and talked to a little boy.

In the second sentence, *talked* is a past participle. It lacks consistency with the sentence, which is in the past continuous tense.

Comment: Awesome! Just downvote an answer without providing a reason.

Comment: The second sentence was correct.  If you look at it as "He (was carrying two ice cream cones) and (talked to a little boy)," the parallelism is correct.